# how to make daily local notification depending on specific time in CVcalendar?

Tags: swift, localnotification

[image]I am using cvcalendar and there is in everyday a different times for fajer, dohor , aser , maghreb , ishaa . for example i have selected the Adan for Fajer, so i want to get the adan in everyday and everyday has a different time. so when i get a notification in DidreceivedLocalNotification i want go to next day in calendar and get the time of the next day, knowing that am getting the times from CoreData .

in viewWillappear

```
        let date = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let calendarForDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let componentsForDate = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)

        let year =  componentsForDate.year
        let month = componentsForDate.month
        let day = componentsForDate.day
        //////////
        //// Conditions after selecting the user (vibration, beep, Adan ) these conditions are testing the selected choice to send a notification to the user on his choice
        //



        if prayerCommingFromAdan.id == 0 && prayerCommingFromAdan.ringToneId != 0{

            notificationId.id = 0
            let hours = prayer0.time[0...1]
            let minutes = prayer0.time[3...4]
            let fajerTime = "\(month)-\(day)-\(year) \(hours):\(minutes)"
            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

            // convert string into date
            let dateValue = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fajerTime) as NSDate!





            var dateComparisionResult:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(dateValue)

            if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
            {
                addNotificationAlarm(year, month: month, day: day, hour: prayer0.time[0...1], minutes: prayer0.time[3...4], soundId: prayerCommingFromAdan.ringToneId, notificationBody: "It is al fajr adan")

            }
```

What should i do in DidreceivedLocalNotification  in AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for scheduling your daily notifications according to time.

```
 func ScheduleMorning() {
        let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        var dateFire=NSDate()

        var fireComponents = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: dateFire)


        if (fireComponents.hour >= 7) {
            dateFire=dateFire.dateByAddingTimeInterval(86400)  // Use tomorrow's date

            fireComponents = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: dateFire)

        }


        fireComponents.hour = 7
        fireComponents.minute = 0
        fireComponents.second = 0

        // Here is the fire time you can change as per your requirement
        dateFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(fireComponents)!

        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = dateFire // Pass your Date here
        localNotification.alertBody = "Your Message here."
        localNotification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)    }
```

for receiving

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        // Do something serious in a real app.
        print("Received Local Notification:")
        print(notification.userInfo)
    }
```

Comment: Anand Thank you, but my problem is how to get times for next day in  calendar and how to use  DidreceivedLocalNotification in AppDelegate ?

Comment: I added in the answer for receive code. Please check it.

Comment: You can set time Manually with the use of NSDate for set the Local notification.

Comment: Anand , there is in everyday in calendar 5 different times and we are using the API to get these times for one year. so can't set them manually . All i need how to access the times in the next day to set an automatic notification everyday .

Comment: You can change this code according to your need i am here giving you the way how to do it this thing.

Comment: Anand, would you mind giving me an example for alarm according to my variables please. how to get the times from the next day in calendar ?